# C# How to open a PDF in my project resources?

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a WinForms GUI that has a 'help' context menu. When clicked, I would like to open the user manual for the application. The manual is a pdf which is stored within the application resources.

Question: How do I open this for the user?

Code I'm working with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
bool adobeInstall = false;
RegistryKey adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Adobe");
if (adobe != null)
{
    RegistryKey acroRead = adobe.OpenSubKey("Acrobat Reader");
    if (acroRead != null)
        adobeInstall = true;
}

if (adobeInstall == true)
{
    ///Open the pdf file??
}
```

Comment: `Process.Start("pdf file path")`?

Comment: How do I start(Properties.Resources.mypdf)? I the .start part inst my worries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string locationToSavePdf = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "file name for your pdf file.pdf");  // select other location if you want
File.WriteAllBytes(locationToSavePdf,Properties.Resources.nameOfFile);    // write the file from the resources to the location you want
Process.Start(locationToSavePdf);    // run the file
```

Comment: +1, except you may wish to use `Path.Combine` instead of string.Format... Also, don't forget to clean up after viewing the file!

Comment: Good idea about the Path.Combine, thanks. As for the cleaning I will leave that to Mrshll187 since he might want to write the file in the application folder instead of the temp so no cleaning would be needed then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you need just a path to the PDF file, no need to add it to the resource):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start(“Path_of_PDFFile”)
```

Comment: How do I give it a path. Its within the application resources

Comment: But this file is on your system, I mean C:/Programs/bla-bla? Or not? ;)

Comment: Its bundle in the application when it installs. Its all relative to where it gets placed. hardcoding a path is not an option

Comment: In this case just copy this file to the directory of your application (sub-folder Help e.g. would be nice) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add `using System.Diagnostics;` to your using, and then call:

`Process.Start("path to pdf")`

You won't need to find the PDF Reader exe or anything. Just call the path of the file you want.

Comment: This file is within my application resources. Giving it a file path is the hard part. Do I stream from my resources and recreate the file to some path THEN open it? How do I handle this?

Comment: So the PDF is not stored on your computer at all?

Comment: The path is relative to where the user installs/executes the application. The pdf is a resource of the application itself

Comment: What about `process.Start(Properties.Resources.mypdf)`;` using the code you've got, and your resource path for pdf?

Comment: Process.start() requires a string. what you mentioned above Resources.mypdf will return a byte[]